# How can I use guzzle to send concurrent requests with timeout limits?

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 6 to send concurrent requests like this:

```
public function sendConcurrentRequests() {

    $client = new Client(['timeout' => 5]);

    $promises[] = $client->getAsync('http://example.com/1');
    $promises[] = $client->getAsync('http://example.com/2');
    $promises[] = $client->getAsync('http://example.com/3');

    $results = Promise\unwrap($promises);  

    return $results;
}
```

Each request could take anywhere from 1 to 10 seconds, but I don't want any of the requests to wait for more than 5 seconds (that's why I'm setting the timeout). What I'm hoping would happen is this:

- Request 1, 2 and 3 are started
- Request 2 takes more than 5 seconds, so the request is cancelled and the responses from requests 1 and 3, which responded in time, are returned

This is what is actually happening:
- Request 1, 2 and 3 are started
- Request 2 takes more than 3 seconds, so the unwrap function throws a `ConnectException` and I can't get the response from requests 1 and 3.

How can I make this work so that I can get the valid responses from the requests that returned in time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer before I finished writing the question, but I thought I would still post it in case it helps someone else.

The solution was to replace this call:

`$results = Promise\unwrap($promises);`

With this:

`$results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait(true);`

The `settle` function will not throw an exception if a promise is rejected, allowing you to get the full responses array (with both fulfilled and rejected responses).

Comment: For anyone looking for an explanation of the difference with another example: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=promise#concurrent-requests

Comment: That feature wasn't documented when this question was posted, so I was the one that added it to the docs :D https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/commit/812f3a83e5de84a089369ce07452fa9d45d2dd1d

Comment: \GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($promises)->wait(true);

Comment: its deprecated you should use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Utils::settle

Comment: @kenske Hi appreciate the docs update. I'd like to know how to get the body of the fulfilled and rejected async requests. TIA